# I can not save changes using the save () method laravel 5.5

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm using a method to find the records to change. Follow the code:

```
public function findId($id)
    {
        $subCategoria = $this->model::join(
                'categoria', 'categoria.id', '=', 'sub_categoria.id_categoria')
            ->select(
                'sub_categoria.id AS id_sub_categoria',
                'sub_categoria.nome AS nome_sub_categoria',
                'categoria.nome AS nome_categoria',
                'categoria.id as id_categoria'
            )
            ->where('sub_categoria.id', $id)
            ->where(
                'sub_categoria.id_unidade_de_trabalho',
                Auth::user()->id_unidade_de_trabalho
            )
            ->where(
                'categoria.id_unidade_de_trabalho',
                Auth::user()->id_unidade_de_trabalho
            )
            ->whereNull('sub_categoria.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('categoria.deleted_at')
            ->first();

        return $subCategoria;
    }
```

My update method looks like this:

```
public function update(array $data, $id)
    {
        $model = $this->findId($id);

        $model->nome = $data['nome'];
        $model->id_categoria = $data['id_categoria'];

        return $model->save();
    }
```

Funny that when I use the find method, which is extended from Model, it works!

Comment: You seem to be trying to update an aliased column.  You're really breaking the functionality of the ORM by using a join with a bunch of aliases.

Comment: So, you suggest I save this record manually, without using Eloquent? Is there anything else?

Comment: I suggest you read up more on SQL so you understand what you're doing.  Eloquent doesn't know these are aliases and not columns, so you're attempting to send an update with the wrong column names.

Comment: @Devon Thank you in advance for your help! When you suggest that I read more about SQL, would it be because there is some error in the way I am building my SQL query? I understood your explanation of how Eloquent works. In this case, would you have any suggestions for resolving this? I know I could use manual methods to make persistence, but I wanted to be able to harness the power of Eloquent.